# Как подтянуть собственный пакет через Maven?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, jar

Я написал модуль.
В pom.xml я использую настройку spring-boot для сборки проекта:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>ru.Main</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>
```

После того, как в IDEA я выполняю install jar-ник попадает в локальный репозиторий мавена .m2/repository/

После этого, я в новом проекте в pom.xml добавляю зависимость на мой пакет:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.bityard.asterisk</groupId>
            <artifactId>ami</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

IDEA его видит, и подгружает.

Теперь я пытаюсь создать экземпляр класса из этого пакета и не получается...
Причем IDEA сама спрашивает добавить import на пакет? я соглашаюсь и ничего не происходит...

[image: скрин IDEA]

я пытаюсь руками прописать путь

```
import ru.bityard.asterisk
```

но IDEA его не видит...

Я посмотрел, что во всех пакетах, подгружаемых мавеном путь к классам начинается с корня пакета, ну например:

```
org/springframework/...
```

а у меня в пакете, путь начинается

```
BOOT-INF/classes/ru/...
```

Может в этом дело? 
Помогите разобраться.

Comment: `jar` попал в локальный `.m2` репозиторий?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да, конечно. И его IDEA видит и подтягивает, когда я его в pom.xml указываю. Я в скриншот приложил в посте. Там видно, что пакет подтянулся в зависимости

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто, `spring-boot-maven-plugin` собирает spring-boot приложение - это конечный продукт. Вам же нужно чтобы `ami` был в качестве API для другого проекта.

Тут несколько путей решения, например, добавить classifier

```
<configuration>
  <mainClass>ru.Main</mainClass>
  <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
</configuration>
```

тогда при сборке будет создаваться два jar: `ami.jar` и `ami-spring-boot.jar` при `install`/`deploy` в репозиторий будет попадать только `ami.jar` - это как раз API для других проектов.

Comment: Спасибо большое!